# Textarea has mysterious whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

For some reason the textarea i am appending to using jquery creates white space.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var artistName = $("#artist-name").text();
  var songName = $("#song-title").text();
  var prepopulated_tweet = "@Myrfriends @RndomPerson \"you'll love this track\" @" + artistName + " - " + songName + " #Rock #Pop #Soul Krilex.******.co/rx11"
  $("#tweet-message").append(prepopulated_tweet);
})
```

html

```
<textarea name="name" rows="4" cols="80" id="tweet-message"></textarea>
```

output

> @Myrfriends @RndomPerson "you'll love this track" @Krilex -
>
> Pieces - Red
>
> #Rock #Pop #Soul Krilex.*****.co/rx11

any clues?

Comment: where is your white space exactly?

Comment: Maybe because artistName and songName contain a carriage return? Can you show the html for these two fields?

Comment: Did you mean whitespace or carriage return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content in `#song-title` element must have new lines.

Given:

```
<div id="song-title">
  Pieces - Red
</div>
```

`$("#song-title").text();` would return:

```
"
  Pieces - Red
"
```

Comment: actually inspecting the element in browser it does not show any lines like you demonstrate but maybe you were referring to html itself, adding a `.trim()` seem to fix the problem. so thank you!

Comment: See the source of your HTML and you will see them.